# Could someone explain how to use the plugin vuejs-progress-bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progress-bar

I am new to vue.js.

I want to use the plugin [vuejs-progress-bar](https://vuejsexamples.com/progressbar-for-vue-js-2/)
 but don't understand how the options struct works. How do I implement it in my export default in the script tag?

It throws an error saying that options is not defined on the instance but referenced during render if I try to make it a property. How do I go about using it?

**Edit: I have tried it this way**

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <progress-bar
    :options="options"
    :value="value"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:"ProgressBar",
  options: {
  text: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    shadowEnable: true,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    dynamicPosition: false,
    hideText: false
  },
  progress: {
    color: '#2dbd2d',
    backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0'
  },
  layout: {
    height: 35,
    width: 140,
    verticalTextAlign: 61,
    horizontalTextAlign: 43,
    zeroOffset: 0,
    strokeWidth: 30,
    progressPadding: 0,
    type: 'line'
  }
}
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: could you show us some code

Comment: Put it in your component's `data`.

Comment: I have added the code after editing, Please have a look. Sorry, I am new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your component's `data` property:

```
export default {
  name:"ProgressBar",
    data: function () {
        return {
            options: {
                text: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    shadowEnable: true,
                    shadowColor: '#000000',
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                    dynamicPosition: false,
                    hideText: false
                },
                progress: {
                    color: '#2dbd2d',
                    backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0'
                },
                layout: {
                    height: 35,
                    width: 140,
                    verticalTextAlign: 61,
                    horizontalTextAlign: 43,
                    zeroOffset: 0,
                    strokeWidth: 30,
                    progressPadding: 0,
                    type: 'line'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```